# Unable to pass IEnumerable<Triangle> into a function that is looking for IEnumerable<IShape>

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, interface, ienumerable

I have a collection of objects:

```
 IEnumerable<Triangle>
```

These objects support an interface `IShape` but i am getting an error trying to pass this into a function that is asking for:

```
 IEnumerable<IShape>
```

1. Why can't I pass this in?
2. Is there any workaround to convert one to the other to get this to work?

Comment: Which version of .NET?  Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: Looks like .NET 3.5 which would explain the error - covariance and contravariance for IEnumerable are new in C# 4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In .NET 4, this should be supported, as `IEnumerable<T>` is declared to be covariant, i.e. the declaration is really `IEnumerable<out T>`. In .NET 3.5, that is not the case, and you would need to use a workaround such as

```
triangles.Cast<IShape>()
```

(It's worth noting this was a language feature evolution as well; that is, if you somehow were able to use C# 3 with .NET 4, it would still not work, because support for co- and contravariance was not added to C# until version 4 of the language.)

An excellent explanation of co- and contravariance can be found in Jon Skeet's [*C# in Depth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471),  section 13.3.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple:

### `IEnumerable<Triangle>` does not inherit from and is not assignable to `IEnumerable<IShape>`<sup>*</sup>

There is no relationship of that kind between the two types.  It sounds like you really want a function more like this:

```
void MyFunction<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : IShape
```

That says, "give me a function that accepts any `IEnumerable<T>` where the T inherits from IShape".  Alternatively, you could use the `.Cast<T>()` extension method (it's surprisingly performant).

<sub>* On your version of the .Net Framework</sub>

Comment: What? That is not correct at all; the relation between generic types with type parameters that are inherited from each other is much more complex than simply "inherits from" vs. "not inherits from". Your answer betrays a serious misunderstanding of generics.

Comment: That's a bit unfair - this was true (as you noted in _your_ answer) in .NET 3.5, it's _still_ true (and not complex at all) with any generic type that isn't covariant/contravariant (e.g. if this were `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`), and this answer presents two viable workarounds for that version.